# What is wrong with this JS functions in Firefox works in Chrome doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

When i enter in this page I want to print information and when I am done with it ,I want to redirect me to previous page. And when I enter in previous page I want to reload page automatically one time.In Firefox works perfectly in Chrome doesn't.

print function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.print();
   window.location.reload(history.go(-1));

});
```

when entering the page reload function

```
(function () {
    window.onpageshow = function(event) {
        if (event.persisted) {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Doesn't work both of parts or only second?

Comment: `history.go()` doesn't return anything and `location.reload()` has no parameters. Why is the `history.go()` call an argument of the `location.reload()` call?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: I fixed the problem with history.go .Now the problem is when I go in previous page it doesn't refresh the page in chrome. In Firefox works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help I fixed the problem with one function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.print();
    window.location.replace(document.referrer)

});
```